# Installed package through npm but it does not show in folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I was trying to install jquery through npm but after using following command:

> npm install jquery

I opened the destination folder and the folder was empty. 
(I copied the following text from cmd)

```
> C:\Users\mandar\Desktop\Mady>npm install jquery

    C:\Users\mandar
    `-- jquery@3.1.1

> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\mandar\package.json'

    npm WARN mandar No description
    npm WARN mandar No repository field.
    npm WARN mandar No README data
    npm WARN mandar No license field.
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `package.json` file manually or through cmd by command npm init or `npm install jquery --save`

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a `package.json`. Create a [**one**](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) and then try to install `jQuery`. And instead use

```
npm install jquery --save
```

command to save the jquery dependency in the package.json file

You can do it manually creating `package.json` or by 
`npm init` and passing the steps

Comment: Or use Yarn, which creates on for you if it doesn't exist: https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360

Comment: Also please do add --save flag  if you want the module to be added to package.json

Comment: but is it my foult or npm foult

Comment: @Maddyplusplus it is your fault

Comment: but yesterday i tryed `npm install jquery` and it was perfect and it was also shown in directory

Comment: Won't jQuery also be saved in the `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 0):

As Suren Srapyan mentioned, in order to solve the problem, you need to create a package.json file, which describes the project you're working on. 
The easiest way to create a package.json file is to run `npm init` - this will invoke a terminal-based walkthrough of creating the package.json file.